# jQuery traversing -- parent's closest sibling containing specific element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the height of a "no image" element to the height of its parent item's sibling's child (actual) img element, if it exists. I'm not sure how to form the query. Here's what I have:

```js
var noImage = $('.no-image');
var image = $('.item .item-thumb a.link img.image');

function noImageHeight() {
  noImage.each(function() {
    let thumbHt = $(this).parent('.item').siblings('.item').find(image).height();
    console.log(thumbHt);
    $(this).css('min-height', thumbHt);
  });
}
noImageHeight();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  .item-thumb {
    a.link {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      img {}
      .no-image {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        justify-items: center;
        background-color: gray;
        color: black;
        font-size: 22px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/686/200/120" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="no-image">No Image</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="no-image">No Image</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/686/200/120" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="no-image">No Image</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent of `.no-image` is `.item-thumb`, not `.item`. Use `.closest()` to search up the hierarchy to find the closest container with a class.

Note that `.siblings(".item").find(image).height()` will always return the height of the first image among all the siblings, not the one closest to the one you started from.

```js
var noImage = $('.no-image');
var image = $('.item .item-thumb a.link img.image');

function noImageHeight() {
  noImage.each(function() {
    let thumbHt = $(this).closest('.item').siblings('.item').find(image).height();
    console.log(thumbHt);
    $(this).css('min-height', thumbHt);
  });
}
noImageHeight();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  .item-thumb {
    a.link {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      img {}
      .no-image {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        justify-items: center;
        background-color: gray;
        color: black;
        font-size: 22px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/686/200/120" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="no-image">No Image</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="no-image">No Image</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/686/200/120" alt="img">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="link">
      <div class="no-image">No Image</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change js to

```
var noImage = $('.no-image');
var image = $('.item-thumb a.link img.image');

function noImageHeight() {
  noImage.each(function() {
    let thumbHt = $(this).parents('.item').siblings('.item').find(image).height();
    console.log(thumbHt);
    $(this).css('min-height', thumbHt);
  });
}
noImageHeight();
```

The selector you are using with find() is already filtered to ".image". Also changed "parent" to "parents" as you need to go as many steps up the DOM as needed, rather than just 1.

Comment: It takes either a selector or a collection. If you give it a collection, it filters the collection to the ones that are found as descendants.

Comment: I initially thought the same thing, but I checked the documentation before putting that in my answer.

Comment: You are correct about .find() as of jQuery 1.6, however I also changed the selector to not include .image as that is the sibling you are already checking for in the previous chained statement...

Comment: Thank you both. Helps a lot. I have a decent handle on traversing the DOM with jQuery but I always end up spending too much time on trial and error because I don't understand the methods as well as I should.